# Trying To shuffle letters withing two Array groups

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to create an encryption algorithm for passwords - using two groups of letters  [ a, r, t, w, h, y, i ] and [ n, m, d, e, l, o, p ].
if a word is passed, it converts the word to lowercase then, the letters in the first array are replaced by the letters in the second array, if not found and vice versa. and if a letter does not appear in any of the array, it flushes it out.

```
if Input = " Aminu ", Output = " nrpau ", 
and 
if Input = " Broom ", Output - " bmyyr "
```

heres my code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace dotnet{

    class Project1{

        static void Main(string[] args){

            string Word = Console.ReadLine();  //enter your word or sentence here... 

            string Shuffled = string.Empty;  //create new string to hold the shuffled words... ... 

            string findletters  = "artwhyi";
            char[] findArr = findletters.ToCharArray();

            string replaceletters = "nmdelop";
            char[] replaceArr = replaceletters.ToCharArray();

            //create new list to hold characters.... 
            List<char> newChars = new List<char>();

            for(int j=0; j < findArr.Length; j++){
                if(Word.IndexOf(findArr[j] = -1)){
                   Shuffled = Word.Replace(findArr[j], replaceArr[j]);
                }else{
                   Shuffled = Word.Replace(replaceArr[j], findArr[j]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Shuffled);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting the desired output and I don't know what I am doing wrong..

Comment: This is not encrytion, because it is impossible to decrypt the original input (because of lowercase). What is the use case for this, what are you going to do with that shuffled passwords? I had the strange feeling you are looking for salted, hashed passwords

Comment: i just called it that way, but there are other lined up methods going to act on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues I could pick:

1. When you are iterating through your's replacement arrays, you always choose one or another. The problem with it is that you are always jumping a possible match in the not chosen array (hope this is clear enough).
2. String.Replace(), what this method actually does is: return a new string with the replaced characters. It doesn't change the original string (Word). Therefore, you are always getting the original string and replacing only one character.

All in all, I think that I can suggest an approach to deal with your problem using only simple concepts.

I hope it is helpful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var word = " aminu ".ToCharArray(); // readline word here...           

  string findArr = "artwhyi";
  string replaceArr = "nmdelop";

  for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
  {
    int index = findArr.IndexOf(word[i]);
    if (index != -1)
    {
      word[i] = replaceArr[index];
    }
    else
    {
      index = replaceArr.IndexOf(word[i]);
        if (index != -1)
          word[i] = findArr[index];
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", word));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary of original and replacement strings and use it for replacing the characters in input string. Since the pair of original-replacement characters are in two arrays and could be replaced vice-versa, you could build a dictionary from the arrays, reverse the dictionary, and combine them.  For example,

```
string findletters  = "artwhyi";
string replaceletters = "nmdelop";

var dictionary = findletters.Zip(replaceletters,(x,y)=> new {key=x, value=y}).ToDictionary(x=>x.key,y=>y.value);
var combinedDictionary = new []{dictionary,dictionary.Reverse()}.Merge();
var input = " Aminu ";
var result = string.Join("", input.Select(x=>char.ToLower(x))
                  .Where(x=> combinedDictionary.ContainsKey(x) || x == ' ')
                  .Select(x=> x == ' '?' ':combinedDictionary[x]));
```

Where Reverse and Merge extension methods are defined as.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> Reverse<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
         var dictionary = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();
         foreach (var entry in source)
         {
             if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(entry.Value))
                 dictionary.Add(entry.Value, entry.Key);
         }
         return dictionary;
    } 

     public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Merge<TKey,TValue>(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<TKey,TValue>> source)

    {
        return source.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                         .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                         .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());
    }

}
```